# Set target or property to a sub project with Ant/Eclipse on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I need to switch to Ant, I managed to compile and install the Android apk file but I didn't manage to transmit the property or a specific target to the referenced library.

My code on the build.xml in the referenced library :

```
<echo message="Property value is '${foo.dist}'" />

<target name="AfficherVersionAnt">
  <echo message="Version d'Ant utilisée : ${ant.version}"/>
</target>
```

The same code is functional when I put it in the starting package.

```
<property name="foo.dist" value="true"/>
```

(and for the target, if I launch with the target)

My ant configuration was generated with :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\android" update project -p "D:\project"
```

And I don't see where I could set a link

Can someone help me ? I would need global variables or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse you can define your own variables for ant

Go to external tools configuration > your profile > environnement, and define new environnement variable.